# How do I prevent an infinite loop in my ARM Assembly program?

Tags: loops, input, arm

Update: 4/16/2019 @ 11:46 PM Central. None of my CMP actually work. Pretty much it's jumping to LDR 0 = errorMessage, then re-looping, which is causing the infinite loop. Still trying to work it out.

I am trying to do the following:
 1. Ask the user to enter money: Nickle (N), Dime (D), Quarter (Q), or Dollars (B). Repeat until the user has inserted 55 or MORE cents.
 2. **So what's the problem?** Let's say the user enters N, I am trying to compare the **INPUT** with the ASCII values of (N, D, Q, B) to see if they match up, if so, jump to the **approve** function, store the value in totalMoney, print out how much money is currently inserted, and call getMoneyLoop again. Repeat until I have reached 55 or more cents.

The program will start fine.

1.) Welcome to my store

2.) Enter Money: Nickle (N), etc

3.) User enters: "N"

However, here I am getting:

```
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B).
```

I've been trying crack this puzzle but I can't seem to wrap my head around what is happening.

Thank you,
Z

I've tried changing registers. I had this "infinite loop" problem in my previous program, but it was a lot simpler (imo). I know originally when I was getting an infinite loop, it was because I was using r1 and r2 and these are considered "unpreserved" and it can lead to some wonky things, and when I changed it to r5 and r6, it fixed it.

On this program, I just don't know if my logic is correct.

I'm still rather new and learning it, but can anyone lead me in the right direction?

**I'm only pasting the specific section I'm having trouble with, and any related data to go along with it.**

```
.data

askUserForMoney: .asciz "Enter money: nickel(N), dime(D), quarters (Q), and one dollar bills (B). \n"

input:  .asciz "%d"

totalCash: .asciz "Total is: %d cents\n" 

errorMessage: .asciz "Invalid Selection. Try Again.\n" 

choice: .word 0 

.text

.global main

main:

getMoney:

    stmfd sp!, {lr, r4}

    mov r4,#0

getMoneyLoop:

 cmp r4, #55
 bge exitGetMoney 

 ldr r0, =askUserForMoney
 bl printf

 ldr r0, =input
 ldr r1, =choice
 bl scanf 

 cmp r1, #78
 addeq r4,r4,#5 
 beq approved 


 cmp r1, #68
 addeq r4,r4,#10
 beq approved


 cmp r1, #81
 addeq r4,r4,#25
 beq approved


 cmp r1, #66
 addeq r4,r4,#100
 beq approved 

 ldr r1, =errorMessage
 bl printf
 b getMoneyLoop

approved:
ldr r0, =totalCash
mov r1, r4
bl printf
b getMoneyLoop


exitGetMoney:
    mov r0,r4
    ldmfd sp!, {lr,r4}
    mov pc, lr
```

I should not be getting an infinite loop, but I am.

Comment: After you `bl scanf`, you continue to use `r1` even though it is an unpreserved register.

Answer (score 0):

I think following printf statement may cause the problem,

approved:
mov r1, r4
bl printf
b getMoneyLoop

The output which is set by this printf statement may be treated as input of the subsequent
scanf statement.

Another problem may happen that after entering N for the previous input, the buffer keeps N as valid input for the next turn, so the program behaves in such a way that the user set input N every time.